# MYSQL update with inner join performance

Tags: java, mysql, performance, inner-join

The join is done on the primary key column of both these tables.

I have a doubt if I should fire a select query before the update or will this query be a good alternative?(in terms of performance)

**order item table**

```
order_item_id
order_id
quantity
unit_price
shipping_price
business_id
workflow_id
delivery_id
item_id
```

**Orders table**

```
billing_address_id
shipping_address_id
payment_mode
total_price
shipping_price
customer_id 
order_id
```

Following is the query I fire from my Java service (using jdbc) :

```
UPDATE order_items t1 
 INNER 
  JOIN Orders t2 
    ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id 
   SET t1.workflow_id = ? 
 WHERE  t1.order_item_id = ? 
   and t2.order_id = ? 
   and t2.customer_id = ? 
   and t1.delivery_id = ?
```

**UPDATE : Adding show create table order_items**

```
'CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
`order_item_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`quantity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`unit_price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`shipping_price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`pickup_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`create_TS` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`update_TS` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`business_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`delivery_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`workflow_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`order_item_id`),
 KEY `fk_business_id` (`business_id`),
 KEY `fk_order_id` (`order_id`),
 KEY `fk_item_id` (`item_id`),
 KEY `fk_delivery_id` (`delivery_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_business_id` FOREIGN KEY (`business_id`) REFERENCES `business` (`MID`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_delivery_id` FOREIGN KEY (`delivery_id`) REFERENCES `delivery_mode` (`delivery_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_item_id` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item_business` (`item_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_order_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `Orders` (`order_id`)
```

)

Comment: What would the select do?

Comment: Why do you mention t2 at all?  Seems like you could remove it.

Comment: Sorry, while editing i missed order_id column in Orders table. added now. @RickJames    .

Comment: @Strawberry - If the select return a row it means I am updating the correct row. If it returns empty then I would throw an error

Comment: In general, more queries equals poorer performance, so I would suggest that you stick with whatever you've got - but I guess it wouldn't hurt to 'suck it and see'.

Comment: Fixing the typo invalidates my 'Answer', so I deleted it.

Comment: Your explanation of the "select" is unclear; please show us the `SELECT` and what you mean by "correct row".  Generally, you can restrict an `UPDATE` to the "correct rows" by using a `WHERE` clause; that is equivalent to doing a `SELECT`.

Comment: select * from order_items t1  INNER   JOIN Orders t2 
    ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id 
 WHERE  t1.order_item_id = ? 
   and t2.order_id = ? 
   and t2.customer_id = ? 
   and t1.delivery_id = ?   This is to ensure the customer can only update order that belongs to him/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Talking in theory**

You should have the minimum set of data **before** you do the join, so the join will actually be performed only on the data you need, and that is the case even with the update that is internally a special select and "write this data on the select"

**Talking in practice**

One of the job of any dbms is to perform an agressive level of optimization using database algebra and other stuff, so most of the time the time you spend in optimizing your query is actually futile because your dbms will perform the same level of optimization

**So what**

I would try to have the table the slimmest as possible but without getting too crazy, I performed on a aws db2.micro machine an update query on like 100k rows and it took it like 4 seconds,  so in my opinion, try and see if you're getting the real result you need.

**tl;dr** just try and see if the speed increase